# FQL query to fetch data of a facebook friend

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I want to fetch all the accessible data of friends from facebook (only name, birthday, gender is enough for me now). I have the App ID of user, all I need is just public data so I tried some codes but I am getting name and facebook ID only.
please suggest what should I do in my code?

```js
function statusChangeCallback(response) {
            console.log('statusChangeCallback');
            console.log(response);
            if (response.status === 'connected') {
                testAPI();
            } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
                document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' + 'into this app.';
            } else {
                document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' + 'into Facebook.';
            }
        }
        function checkLoginState() {
            FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
                statusChangeCallback(response);
            });
        }
 
        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
            FB.init({
                appId : '155509608142654',
                cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access
                // the session
                xfbml : true, // parse social plugins on this page
                version : 'v2.5' // use version 2.2
            });
            FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
                statusChangeCallback(response);
            });
 
        };
        
        
        
 
        // Load the SDK asynchronously
        (function(d, s, id) {
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id))
                return;
            js = d.createElement(s);
            js.id = id;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }
        (document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
        function testAPI() {
            console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
            FB.api( '/me?fields=name,friends{age_range,birthday,gender}', function(response) {
                                console.log(response);
                                document.getElementById('userDetails').innerHTML = 'Thanks for logging in, ' + response.name + ' below are your information!' + '<br><b>Name:</b>' + response.name +'<br><b>frnd:</b>' + response.friendgender + '<br><b>frnd list:</b>' + response.friendlists + '<br><b>Facebook link:</b>' + response.link + '<br><b>Local:</b>'  + response.location  + '<br><b>Facebook Id:</b>' + response.id;
```

>

Comment: First of all, that is _not_ FQL, but a normal Graph API call. And you can not get just any information you like about friends via API, most of that stuff needs permission from the friend.

Answer (score 0):

You can only get data of friends who authorized your App too, with the required permissions. Friend permissions have been removed for privacy reasons: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

For example, friends need to authorized your App with the `user_birthday` permission if you want to get their birthday.

Comment: and they do have a birthday, and they did authorize with the user_birthday permission? works fine for me, with your API call.

Comment: btw, i don´t get any age_range, i assume that´s not possible at all.